# T-SQL Statements, Variables, and Single Quotation Marks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm a newbie looking for advice from experienced professionals.

I have a T-SQL query that includes variables for certain values (See below).

```
BEGIN  
  --SET @Where = @Where + ' AND WebName = '''+ @SearchKey + ' '' <br>OR Name = '''+ @SearchKey +''''  
  SET @Where = @Where + ' AND WebName like ''%'+ @SearchKey +  '%'' OR Name like ''%'+ @SearchKey +'%'''
END
```

The problem is when the information gets populated. Some of the variables will need to handle single quotation marks without getting an error. How can I handle the single quotes that are coming from the variable information?

Comment: Little Bobby Tables approves

Comment: You need to escaped them with double.   insert into trouble values ('can''t')  or use a parameterized SQL (not just parameters)

Answer (score 4):

So, let's start off where you are dangerous. You are open to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

You should parameterize your SQL and this will solve the danger issue as well as your rogue apostrophe issue.

Here are some resources you should read and educate yourself with:

1. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html
2. http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: -1 for speculation and not answering the question! I don't agree that this is open to SQL Injection. It's completely self contained code inside SQL. There's no connection, not user input, no client application or website... for all we know it's a stored proc that iterates over a set of trusted data.

Comment: Noticed this comment on my post. Parameterizing the SQL would solve the problem. And that code is absolutely vulnerable to SQL Injection; that is actually the problem the user was encountering. SQL Injection is nothing more than data being formed in a way that makes your SQL behave in an unintended way. No idea why I got a downvote nor his comment an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about escaping the `'` character inside a SQL varchar variable. Escaped once (on set or select) is enough.

See this demo

```
declare @a nvarchar(100),
        @b nvarchar(100),
        @name nvarchar(100)

set @a = 'Hi, ';
set @name = 'Jim''my O''Tool';
set @b = ', you champ.'

select @name
select @a + @name + @b
```